# How to update a Perl/Tk widget textvariable that is a moose attribute?

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit, moose

In Perl/Tk, one can define textvariables for widgets. It's a reference to some scalar that holds the value. 
Someone showed me how to use Moose attribute coercion to use Moose attributes as textvariable (cool!). This is how it works:

```
subtype 'TkRef' => as 'ScalarRef';
coerce 'TkRef', from 'Str', via { my $r = $_; return \$r };
has 'some_val' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'TkRef', coerce => 1, default => 'default value');

$mw->Entry(-textvariable => $self->some_val);
$mw->Label(-textvariable => $self->some_val); # will always Show what we type into the entry
```

However, when I want to set a new value for the attribute, I have to dereference it like this:

```
${$self->some_val} = 'blarg'; # dereference
```

Simply setting the attribute won't work, as the reference needs to remain the same over the life of the object (that is, the attribute value itself cannot change).

Is there a way to use the nice Moose attribute coerce feature without losing the possibility to set the attribute with `$self->some_val('blarg');` ? Some sort of reverse-coercion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the accessors private, and then provide a wrapper for the accessor. Something like this:

```
subtype 'TkRef', as 'ScalarRef';
coerce 'TkRef', from 'Str', via { my $r = $_; return \$r };

has _some_val => (
   is       => 'rw',
   isa      => 'TkRef',
   coerce   => 1,
   init_arg => 'some_val',
   default  => 'default value',
);

sub some_val {
   my $self = shift;
   if (@_ and not ref $_[0]) {
      ${$self->_some_val} = shift;
   }
   elsif (@_ and ref $_[0]) {
      ${$self->_some_val} = ${+shift};
   }
   $self->_some_val(@_);
}
```

Comment: This is so cool. Although the type coercion reminds me of the type-munging stuff of other programming languages - which is I don't and which is why I chose Perl after all - it does exactly what I want it to do. All that's left now is to encapsulate it so I don't have to see / write it every time I have such a variable.